# Помогите с "разбором" .json

Tags: json, android-studio

Хочу вывести из .json элементы,но возникает проблемы:

```
error: cannot find symbol variable buttonParse и Method
error: cannot find symbol class Listener
```

Код:

```
private TextView mTextViewResult;
private RequestQueue mQueue;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    buttonParse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            jsonParse();
            mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.textView);
            Button buttonParse = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        }
    });
}
            private void jsonParse() {
    String url = "http://test.json";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("teaserHTML");

                        for (int i = 0;i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject employee = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            int date = employee.getInt("date");
                            String title = employee.getString("title");
                            String teaserHTML = employee.getString("teaserHTML");
                            int viewsCount = employee.getInt("Views");
                            int commentsCount = employee.getInt("Comments");

                            mTextViewResult.append(String.valueOf(date) + ", " + title + ", " + teaserHTML + ", " + String.valueOf(viewsCount) + ", " + String.valueOf(commentsCount) + "\n\n\n\n");


                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря я не использовал `Volley`, предпочитаю `Retrofit`, но в конкретном случае у вас ошибка в том, что функция вызывается раньше чем вы объявляете объект!

Нужно исправить на:

```
mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.textView);
Button buttonParse = findViewById(R.id.button2);

jsonParse();
```

Comment: buttonParse теперь определяется,но Method и Listener до сих пор нет.